# How to fix sympy LaTeX denominator output?

Tags: python, sympy, tex

I am using Python 2.7 with sympy.
So when I am trying to use LaTeX output, I get an expression, where the denominator is factored out.
And I can't figure out why.
So for `(x*y**2 - 2*x*y*z + x*z**2 + y**2 - 2*y*z + z**2)/(x**2 - 1)`

I get something like:

[image: What comes out]

Instead of something like:

[image: What I want.]

It also works on on their [website](http://live.sympy.org). (Note that it works ok for short things)

The code I used is

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symblos('x y z')
expr = (x*y**2 - 2*x*y*z + x*z**2 + y**2 - 2*y*z + z**2)/(x**2 - 1)
latex(expr)
```

Obviously it gives the TeX code, not the image.

Comment: @Ffisegydd I can but there is no need, you can get the same effect by just entering the equation ' (x*y**2 - 2*x*y*z + x*z**2 + y**2 - 2*y*z + z**2)/(x**2 - 1) ' on [link](http://live.sympy.org) .

Comment: @Ffisegydd Ok. I added the code... If that's what you wanted. Not sure, how this can be useful.

Comment: What is `latex`? Is it a function? Where did it come from? I'm not going to answer this question as I don't know the answer, but if someone is able to answer it, chances are they'll want the full details.

Comment: @Ffisegydd I added all the code. Is it better now?

Comment: @Ffisegydd I don't get why would you need MY code, since live.sympy.org is an interactive console and just typing the command in there would work. To help me you could read the documentation (maybe I missed somethign when I read it) or if you are experienced you may know the answer...

Comment: @Ffisegydd Thank you anyway. I am new to stackoverflow soo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you never want the denominator pulled out, set the long_frac_ratio to oo. The `ee` defined below has the same symptoms as your expression; notice that setting the ratio forces it into simple over/under format:

```
>>> ee
(-2*x*y*z + x)/(x - 1)
>>> latex(ee)
'\\frac{1}{x - 1} \\left(- 2 x y z + x\\right)'
>>> latex(ee,long_frac_ratio=oo)
'\\frac{- 2 x y z + x}{x - 1}'
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. BTW, sorry, `oo` is infinity sign, right?

Comment: Note that in this specific instance (`expr` in the question), `long_frac_ratio=6` is sufficient.